# difference between docker service and docker container

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I can create a docker container by command

```
docker run <<image_name>>
```

I can create a service by command

```
docker service create <<image_name>>
```

What is the difference between these two in behaviour?

When would I need to create a service over container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`docker service` command in a [docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) replaces the `docker run`.  `docker run` has been built for single host solutions. Its whole idea is to focus on local containers on the system it is talking to. Whereas in a cluster the individual containers are irrelevant. We simply use swarm services to manage the multiple containers in a cluster. Swarm will orchestrate the containers of the services for us.

`docker service create` is mainly to be used in [docker swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/). `docker run` does not have the concept of scaling up/down. With `docker service create` you can specify the number of replicas to be created using the `--replicas` command. This will create and manage multiple replicas of a containers in many different nodes. There are several such options for managing multiple containers using `docker service create` and other commands under `docker service ...`

One more note: docker services are for container orchestration systems(swarm). It has built in facility for failure recovery. ie. it recreates a container on failure. `docker run`would never recreate a container if it fails. When the `docker service` commands are used we are not directly asking to perform action like "create a single container", rather we are saying to the orchestration system to "put this job in your queue and when you can get to it perform that action on the swarm". This means it has rollback facilities, failure mitigation and lots of intelligence built in.

You need to consider using `docker service create` when in swarm mode and `docker run` when not in swarm mode. You can lookup on docker swarms to understand docker services.

Comment: Can I make the service to join sworm while creating one?

Comment: Swarm is deactivated by default. You need to initialize by `docker swarm init` then services created will be in the swarm. Please lookup on swarm to understand services.

Comment: your answer is great, but the statement "docker run would never recreate a container if it fails" is wrong `docker run --restart on-failue` will do exactly that

Comment: So does a Docker service contain a number of Docker containers?  If that's the case, given a service id or name, how do I find out which Docker containers are inside that service?  Or vice versa, given a container id, how do I find out which Service that container belongs to?  I ask because given a Service name, I want to ssh into any of the Containers within that service. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real difference. In the official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#introduction) you can read "Services are really just containers in production".

Services can be declared in "docker-compose.yml" and can be started from it. Once started, they will run as containers.

It is just a common way to name parts of your stack.

Comment: Agreed with that part, but those are created through `docker stack deploy`. I am having more specific that I can create a service through command too. So, is there use-case I would use the `docker service create` command directly?

Comment: docker stack deploy would run on cluster swarm. If you don't have any cluster swarm, it wouldn't run. But if you have many services in your docker-compose file, you can just start them by calling docker-compose command which will create services for you. 
However, you can not do everything in docker-compose. For example, if you want to declare how many replicas to be started for one service, it won't run. docker stack is required for that.

Comment: Let's have a look into the official documentation : https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/.
The sample docker-compose file declares 2 services "web" and "redis". To start them all together or one by one, you can use docker-compose command. 
But if you want to create services yourself, your command is also right.

Comment: @OlivierTerrien On the basis that "Services are really just containers in production",  then how would I ssh into that container?  To ssh into a Docker Container, I can do e.g. `docker exec -it docker exec -it 1a2b3c4d5e6 /bin/bash` where `1a2b3c4d5e6` is a Docker Container id which is a hexadecimal id. A Service ID is alphanumber e.g. `qshbw3hciwv1` and will give an error if I try to use it with that command? So could you advise please?